# jQuery Cycle2 synchronise multiple slideshows to run one after the other

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have 6 jQuery cycles on one page, I want the first cycle to change and then pause and then I want the second cycle to change after a few seconds and pause and so on until the last cycle and then it goes back to the beginning again.

I saw something someone had posted but it doesn't work on my code:

```
$('.cycle').each(function(){
   $(this).cycle({
      delay:   -8000 + (2000 * (i+1)),
      timeout:  8000
   });
});
```

my code is:

```
<div class="cycle">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/one.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/two.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/three.png">
</div>
<div class="cycle">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/two.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/three.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/one.png">
</div>
<div class="cycle">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/three.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/one.png">
   <img alt="" src="_assets/images/two.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the events section of the api documentation:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

It looks like the `cycle-finished` trigger is what you're looking for.

Inside the each, try adding the event:

```
$(this).cycle({
  delay:   -8000 + (2000 * (i+1)),
  timeout:  8000
}).on( 'cycle-finished', function( event, opts ) {
   ....
});
```